# How to abort a macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that goes through a directory and looks at all its files. Unfortunately the directory is on a mapped network drive so the process is really slow.

How can I kill the macro?

Comment: That's a bummer. I guess you don't have access to the machine it's running on?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can stop a macro by pressing the keys: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>break</kbd>

Comment: works most of the time under normal circumstances but if the macro is hanging or otherwise unresponsive, you probably just have to kill the process from task manager.